# What is the correct way to prompt the mouse cursor to reappear if it was hidden because the user was typing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse

I have a control in a WPF application that contains a text box and a submit button. The submit button is set as the "default" so that if the user presses Enter while the cursor is in the text box, the click handler for the button is run. The process kicked off by the click handler is lengthy, so I use a wait cursor coded like the following:

```
public class WaitCursor: IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Windows.Input.Cursor _oldCursor = null;

    public WaitCursor()
    {
        _oldCursor = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor;
        System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
        // *** 1
    }

    ~WaitCursor()
        => Dispose(false);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose(bool unused)
    {
        System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = _oldCursor;
        // *** 2
    }
}
```

If I type in the text box, the mouse cursor disappears. This is standard behaviour on Windows that I have observed in many applications. However, if I type in the text box and then press Enter without moving the mouse, then the mouse cursor is not shown while the application is busy - even if the user is moving it around. Effectively, the mouse cursor becomes invisible whenever it's over my application's windows, and remains that way until the application ceases being busy. This is undesirable.

I tried adding `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Show()` at the position marked with `// *** 1` in my code above. This solved the problem of the cursor not being shown. But it introduced a new problem, in that the cursor no longer gets automatically hidden when the user types into text boxes in the application thereafter (for the lifetime of the application). [The documentation page on Cursor.Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.show(v=vs.110).aspx) says that calls to the Show() and Hide() methods should be paired, so I tried adding `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide()` at the position marked with `// *** 2`. This fixed all observed issues.

But I am not comfortable with this solution, for 2 reasons:

- I am using a combination of the facilities provided by System.Windows.Forms.Cursor and System.Windows.Input.Cursor. This feels like it must be incorrect.
- I am not comfortable instructing the application to "hide" the cursor when I do not in fact want the cursor to be hidden, even though the observed behaviour is that I merely undo the effect of the earlier call to Show(). It seems like something that isn't the intent of the framework designers (it really looks like what they had in mind was that you would Hide() the cursor and later Show() it) and might therefore break unpredictably.

What's the correct/proper way of solving this problem? If there is an officially sanctioned way to do this then I want to do that.

Comment: For instance, look at Windows logon, when it's busy there is a progress ring encompassing the whole screen, making it really clear as on what's happening .

Answer (score 0):

What about *moving* (simulated from code behind) the `mouse` before you start your process?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyDown += _OnKeyDown;
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };
    public static Point GetMousePosition()
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
        return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
    }

    private void _OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        if (keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Point pos = GetMousePosition();
            SetCursorPos((int)pos.X + 1, (int)pos.Y); //move 1 pixel
            SetCursorPos((int)pos.X - 1, (int)pos.Y); //move back to original position

            //start your process afterwards ..
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's an approach I hadn't thought of. I think I would find it hard to justify adding this kind of code to the project if anybody queried it. I will be trying this out to see if it works, although I'm not going to be in a position to resume work for a few days.

Comment: My solution approaches would be to implement it in a `baseClass`, `AttachedBehavior` or `Behavior`. So you it is very easy to implement.